# IndentationError: expected an indented block, Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

> career@careercrawler:~/stack/stack$ scrapy crawl stack
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/career/.local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(execute())
>
> File
>   "/home/career/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py",
>   line 141, in execute
>       cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
>
> File
>   "/home/career/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py",
>   line 238, in **init**
>       super(CrawlerProcess, self).**init**(settings)
>
> File
>   "/home/career/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py",
>   line 129, in **init**
>       self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
>
> File
>   "/home/career/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py",
>   line 325, in _get_spider_loader
>       return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
>
> File
>   "/home/career/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py",
>   line 33, in from_settings
>       return cls(settings)
>
> File
>   "/home/career/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py",
>   line 20, in **init**
>       self._load_all_spiders()
>
> File
>   "/home/career/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py",
>   line 28, in _load_all_spiders
>       for module in walk_modules(name):
>
> File
>   "/home/career/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py",
>   line 71, in walk_modules
>       submod = import_module(fullpath)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in
>   import_module
>       **import**(name)
>
> File "/home/career/stack/stack/spiders/stack_spider.py", line 4, in
>   
>       from stack.items import StackItem
>
> File "/home/career/stack/stack/items.py", line 13
>       title = scrapy.Field()
>           ^
>
> IndentationError: expected an indented block

This is my error, I don't know what is happening there. Someone help me, please.

Comment: line 13 `title = scrapy.Field()` in `items.py` is underindented.

Answer (score 1):

This error is because of intention,
As mentioned in the traceback:

> /home/career/stack/stack/items.py", line 13 title = scrapy.Field()

go to `~/stack/stack/items.py` and check indentation at `line 13`.

Comment: not thing wrong there because these file can run on windows but when i try it on ubutun, the error is appear

Comment: Can you attach the code here? The error could also occur if you have used space instead of tab or vice versa.